# Display Datagridview data along with Column names in crystal report?

Tags: c#, datagridview, crystal-reports, windowsformshost

I want to display datagridview data along with column names in crystal report. I do not want to use database expert fields. I've tried so far this code to fetch the data within datagridview but am unable to display it in crystal report.

```
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow item in this.dataGridView6.Rows)
            {

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                if (item.DataBoundItem != null)
                {
                    dr = (DataRow)((DataRowView)item.DataBoundItem).Row;
                    dt.ImportRow(dr);
                }
            }
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                ReportDocument myReportDocument;
                myReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
                myReportDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\habib\Downloads\GMT\GarmentsManagmentSystem\GarmentsManagmentSystem\crystal_report.rpt");
                myReportDocument.SetDataSource(ds.Tables);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myReportDocument;
                this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage6;
```

Any help would highly be appreciated. Thanks